# What tractates have been studied at Yeshiva University?

Tags: talmud-gemara, yeshiva-school, college-university-school

Tractates at YU RIETS are chosen once a seven-year cycle. I am curious in finding out if an entire list exists?

For example, this [article from 2002](http://commie.droryikra.com/v66i12/features/talmud.shtml) discusses the tractates chosen for the next seven years:

> The Rashei HaYeshiva decided on the following list of masechtot slated for study over the next six years: 5763 - Ketubot, perek Alef; 5764 - Sanhedrin, perek Alef; 5765 - Shabbos, perek Zayin; 5766 - Kiddushin, perek Beis; 5767 - Baba Kamma, perek Zayin; and 5768 - Berachos, perek Vav.
>
> Many students were surprised to hear that RIETS chooses a new set of masechtot every seven years.  The majority of students that were asked assumed that the yeshiva followed a concrete, repetitive, seven-year cycle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be focused on a general Judaism topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA This looks squarely on-topic to me. It's about the history of and perhaps best practices in Judaism. It could be improved if minhag would [edit] in more information about why such a history would be worth having.

Comment: I think @DanF is right on this one. Why isn't this off-topic as about Jews independent of Judaism?

Comment: @DonielF I also think this may be "localized". I don't think that there is a standard cycle followed by all yeshivot. If there is, then O.P. can greatly improve and make this question more relevant by providing a source for that and questioning why, perhaps, Y.U. has a different standard.

Comment: @DonielF there's nothing "independent of Judaism" about teaching Torah.